# Socket.io, Unreal, & Heroku (Node js) : Client not connecting to server?

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io, unreal-engine4

I'm currently working on a game that connects to a Node.js server for multiplayer data.

The game is developed in Unreal Engine 4 and uses the Socket.io plugin to connect to the Node.js server (cors, express being used).

Everything works locally. So now I'm trying to move on to hosting the server remotely and connecting the unreal client to the remote Node.js server.

I looked into Heroku and set myself up, everything is working fine on its end to my knowledge - I created a tester page with a success message when you load the URL and that comes through.

My first question is - what am I doing wrong when I use unreal to point the socket.io plugin to the server url?

The socket.io plugin asks for a port #, I've tried the following:

```
http:/{my server/heroku url}:8080/
http:/{my server/heroku url}:3000/
http:/{my server/heroku url}:18279/ (which was given to me by Heroku).
http:/{my server/heroku url}/
```

So far the game does not connect to the deployed server, the way it does locally.

Any suggestions on what could be going wrong/what am I failing to do next?

A few things after researching:

- I do have http-session-affinity enabled
- Since the server is working locally, I'm going to make the assumption that the deployed code is not the issue, and that it has to do with the way I'm trying to connect.
- is it possible that I have further authorization to config? Such as allowing the unreal game/client to connect to the server/that the client is being blocked some how?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, it had to do with how my Node.js server code was calling socket.io.

If you come across this issue please send me a message or comment here and I will be happy to send you the code that worked.